# Performance of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], or define("SITE_ROOT", ""]);

Tags: php

I need to store the document root to be used across my application

I have two options, would someone please mind explaining what would be quicker and why? Or indeed if there is a better way to achieve this.

```
define("SITE_ROOT", "/"]);

$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path/to/file"
```

so an include would be created as;

```
require(SITE_ROOT.'/path/to/file');
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path/to/file");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use:

```
define("SITE_ROOT", "/");  //Typo removed
```

Is a just a little little bit faster than:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/path/to/file"
```

Since you always concatenate something, is the constant a bit faster. But I think this falls under micro management and I don't think that this is your biggest performance issue in your code.

Even if this would be your "biggest performance issue", even then I would say the difference is so small you can decide, what you want to use and what you think is more readable.

Comment: perfect, thanks for the explanation Rizier. I know it will be an extremly negligible improvement. Just like to learn how and why, hadnt thought about the impact of concerntraiting it!

Comment: @Muhammet Please read my full answer: *Since you always concatenate something, is the constant a bit faster*

Comment: In fact, I tested it and variable seems to be faster than a constant.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there shouldn't be any performance difference *(You shouldn't be worrying about this kind of stuff)*, but this seems way cleaner, readable and especially ***easier to type***:

```
require(SITE_ROOT.'/path/to/file');
```

than

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path/to/file");
```